# First and last item behaving like space-between is set, all middle items as if flex-start is set

Tags: html, css

**OBJECTIVE**

I'd like the first and last items of a vertical container to behave like the parent is set to `justify-content: space-between` while every other item in the middle behaves as if it were set to `justify-content: flex-start`

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

Using both `flex` and `grid` containers. I fiddled with all settings and tried some tentative solutions provided by ChatGPT, such as using `margin-top: auto` and `grid-template-rows: auto 1fr 1fr auto;`

**STRUCTURE**

Below is a simplified example of the structure I need. Notice how **Item 3** has variable height in each card. I need their tops to be aligned so that all extract space is at the bottom.

```css
#project-list {
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: stretch;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 20px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
}


.project-card {
    background: #e5e5e5;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
    padding: 0 28px;
}
```

```html
<div id="project-list">
  <div class="project-card">
    <div><B>Item 1 - This item should be flush with the top</B></div>
    <div>Item 2 - This item should be flush with the one above it</div>
    <div><i>Item 3 - This item should be flush with the one above it<BR>
    Lorem ipsum blablablablablabal<BR>
    Lorem ipsum blablablablablabal<BR>
    Lorem ipsum blablablablablabal<BR>
    Lorem ipsum blablablablablabal<BR>
    Lorem ipsum blablablablablabal</i></div>
    <div><B>Item 4 - This item should be flush with the bottom</B></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="project-card">
    <div><B>Item 1 - This item should be flush with the top</B></div>
    <div>Item 2 - This item should be flush with the one above it</div>
    <div><i>Item 3 - This item should be flush with the one above it<BR>
    Lorem ipsum blablablablablabal<BR>
    Lorem ipsum blablablablablabal<BR>
    Lorem ipsum blablablablablabal</i></div>
    <div><B>Item 4 - This item should be flush with the bottom</B></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="project-card">
    <div><B>Item 1 - This item should be flush with the top</B></div>
    <div>Item 2 - This item should be flush with the one above it</div>
    <div><i>Item 3 - This item should be flush with the one above it<BR>
    Lorem ipsum blablablablablabal<BR></i></div>
    <div><B>Item 4 - This item should be flush with the bottom</B></div>
  </div>

</div>
```

**VISUAL ILLUSTRATION OF WHAT I WANT**

https://i.ibb.co/7JYqPk1/image.png